# Adobe Illustrator: How can I change the profile of a dashed stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, effects, line-art, outline

How can I change the profile of a dashed stroke?

Here's a little swatch to show what I mean:

[image]

1. On top is a copy of #2, with the **Dashed Line** option selected.
2. In the middle is a simple horizontal line (stroke); just a straight, open path consisting of two aligned nodes and a tapered **Profile**.
3. Below is a resized version of #2 with **Weight** reduced, repeated 13 times. It's supposed to be similar to #1, but with a tapered profile applied to each dash/segment of the stroke.

What I want to do is #3. It's easy enough to do it manually for a single straight line, but it gets difficult real fast when you start dealing with more complex objects, even relatively simple, well defined shapes like letters for instance:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not possible with a dashed stroke. Make a **Pattern Brush** instead:

[image: Pattern Brush]

[image: Brush Options]

[image: Result]

Once the brush is applied, it's possible to change options from the **Stroke Panel**:

[image: Stroke Panel]

Fix the *conflict corners* editing the brush and changing the flip axis:

[image: conflict corners]

Or add a minim dash to the brush shape and change the dash alignment:

[image: dash alignment]

Comment: There's no conflicts in corners if you break the paths at the corners with the scissors tool. It's also useful to insert space in the brush options and allow stretching, if there's a long space.